# Best way to define class-scoped constant in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, static, constants

I need to use some constant value in a `cpp` file which is related to a class and won't be used outside of it.

I came up with several methods of doing this:

#### Method 1: `static const` in a `.cpp` file

```
static const int a = 100; // <<<

int Class::foo() const
{
    return a + 10;
}

int Class::bar() const
{
    return a - 10;
}
```

If I get this right, I can also omit the `static` keyword as the `const` automatically implies the internal linking in this context.
Please, *correct me if I'm wrong*.

#### Method 2: Anonymous namespace (C++11)

Basically same as the previous but:

```
namespace
{
    const int a = 100;
}
```

I believe this method is the preferred way to declare such scoped constants over the previous one in C++11.
Again, *correct me if I'm wrong*.

#### Method 3: `static const` in a `.h` file

```
class Class
{
public:
    int foo() const;
    int bar() const;
protected:
    static const int a = 100; // <<<
};
```

#### Method 4: non-static `const` in `.h` (C++11)

```
class Class
{
public:
    int foo() const;
    int bar() const;
protected:
    const int a = 100; // <<<
};
```

Or like this: `const int a{100}`. I think there is no difference for POD types.
And once again, *correct me if I'm wrong*.

#### Method 5: initializer list

```
class Class
{
public:
    Class() : a(100) {} // <<<
    int foo() const;
    int bar() const;
protected:
    const int a;
};
```

#### Summing up

I guess I must not use methods 1 and 2 as they will fail if I'll ever need to create a subclass.

Also, I think that the method 5 will be hard to maintain if there are many overloaded constructors.

Though the question may be considered opinion-based, mainly I'm trying to figure out the pros and cons of these methods, and probably there are some other possible solutions.

Comment: In #4 and #5  you increase the class size by at least `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: I would think #3 is the best for your usecase. But making it `static constexpr` would be even better in my opinion.

Comment: Use the one that fits your current situation best (#2) and change it if you need to in the future. There are no "ideal now and forever and ever" solutions to anything except truly trivial problems.

Comment: Are subclasses allowed to change the value of this constant?

Comment: #1 & #2 are the same and cannot be considered “class scoped” - it can be accessed from anywhere within the same file.

Comment: @SacrificerXY No, they aren't.

Comment: @TheFailurebyDesign I understand that. However, the file in my case contains only a single class, so (roughly speaking) this constants could be also considered class-scoped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For ordinary global variables, `const` does imply `static` (but note that `const char *f;` isn’t const), so #1 with or without `static` is indeed the same.  (This is really a misfeature, included as an emulation of `constexpr inline` many years before variables could have those.)  #2 is also the same (preferred only in that **types** can also be declared in an anonymous namespace but cannot be declared `static`).

These are not *intrinsically* bad for derived classes: they restrict the constant to a *source file*, which can define methods for as few or as many classes as you like.  You can also put them in `.hpp` files, although preferring a class member is reasonable.

For #3, note that the variable need not be **initialized** in the class definition.  Doing so lets it be used in constant expressions in every file that includes the header, in which case the modern style (which supports non-integer variables) is to use `constexpr`.

#4 and #5 add a member to every class object and are best avoided—consider that they disable the default **assignment** operators.